# Do I need to publish to the play store to cast to chromecast?

Tags: java, android, casting, chromecast

I'm trying to cast to a chromecast with my android app. I have followed all the steps here. https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers

I published the app in the cast developer console and got the published app id. I also tried with the public ones, but the cast button simply won't appear.

Chromecast and device are both connected to the same wifi.

It works if I connect within the options in android's upper panel, but I need it inside the app.
I don't know what I'm missing. That's why I'm thinking this might be the problem. That the app is not in playstore. I have no intention to publish it, so I cannot try just to test.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello Maria, welcome to SO! I haven't done Chromecast programming since 2013-2014, but I suspect things are mostly the same; in my experience, you *do not need* to have your app in the playstore before you can run, debug, and use Chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not running on localhost, you will have to use https